# Looping through a firebase array and adding up the contents of one of its elements with ReactJS?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, firebase, function

In firebase I have a few arrays stored that are something like(schools, Students, Fundraisers, etc). Within my Fundraisers array I have an element that is amountRaised which states how much was raised at each particular fundraiser. I would like to loop through my fundraiser array and add up the amountRaised for all of the fundraisers to give me a total amount raised. I am pretty new to Firebase, react and Javascript, and I thought I could do it like so in a function inside my component but outside my render and return:

```
totalRaised = 0.0;
addFunds(){
    for(let i = 0; i < this.state.fundraisers.length; i++){
        this.totalRaised = this.totalRaised + this.fundraisers[i].amountRaised;
    }
    return this.totalRaised;    
}
```

When I call the component I want to pass the total raised through I pass through totalRaised={this.totalRaised} and I output a value of zero. When I try passing though the functionI dont output anything. I tried setting totalRaised to totalRaised=this.fundraisers[0].amountRaised to just see if I was able to get totalRaised equal to the first element of the arrays amountRaised value and that yielded nothing or errors. This obviously leads me to think my issue is with how I am passing in my data value of amountRaised to my total raised variable. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple of things I would recommend for you here.

1. Use the actual value (not the function to calculate it) in the render function
2. Simplify your calculation by using the [`Array.reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) function (optional)

It looks like you're using `this.state`, so I assume your component is a class component. To get this working as minimally, just compute the value by calling your function right where you want it to be used in your render function:

```
class FundraiserTotalRaised extends Component {
  addFunds = () => this.state.fundraisers.reduce(
    (totalRaised, fundraiser) => totalRaised + fundraiser.amountRaised,
    0
  );

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        // As child text, remember to call it
        <p>Raised: ${this.addFunds()}</p>

        // As a prop, also remember to call it
        <SomeOtherComponent totalRaised={this.addFunds()} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Computing values inline like this is generally a bad idea because it can lead to performance issues:

- If there are lots of fundraisers, the loop could take a while and you don't want to do that every render
- Recalculating the same thing every render (or multiple times a render) is a waste of resources

For those reasons, it would be a good idea to move it to the component's state, so **it is only recomputed when the list of fundraisers change**. That might look something like this, a bit closer to what I think you have implemented already.

```
class FundraiserTotalRaised extends Component {

  // Initialize the component state
  state = {
    // ...
    totalRaised: 0,
  };

  componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
    if (this.state.fundraisers !== prevState.totalRaised) {
      // When the list of fundraisers changes, compute the new total
      const newTotalRaised = this.addFunds();
      // Actually update the value in state so that the change is reflected on the UI
      this.setState({ totalRaised: newTotalRaised });
    }
  }

  addFunds = () => this.state.fundraisers.reduce(
    (totalRaised, fundraiser) => totalRaised + fundraiser.amountRaised,
    0
  );

  render() {
    return (
      <p>Raised ${this.state.totalRaised}</p>
    );
  }
}
```

State management and passing props correctly are the core building blocks to every React application. If you're unfamiliar with it, definitely checkout [React's practical tutorial](https://reactjs.org/tutorial/tutorial.html). It does a good job of walking you through state management for class based components.

Comment: Thank you very much! I was able to solve it and I am for sure going to go through the practice tutorial as well.

Comment: No problem, glad I could help!